# Prevent steamcloud updating keyboard config

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

I have a desktop computer with a big keyboard and a laptop with a laptop keyboard (both Macs). I'm left handed so I tend to configure the numeric keypad to do what the WSAD keys normally do so I can use the keyboard with my right hand.  Of course the laptop doesn't have a numeric keypad so I configure that to use the keys to the right of the keyboard instead.

Unfortunately, whenever I play a steam cloud game (Portal 2, Left 4 Dead, TF2, etc), it downloads the keyboard configuration I used last. If the last keyboard I used was the laptop then the desktop keys get moved to a less-than-comfortable position.  Worse, if the last keyboard was the desktop, then the laptop gets configured to use keys that don't even exist!

How to I keep the steamcloud enabled games from sharing their keyboard configurations without preventing them from sharing the other data that gets pushed to the cloud?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment is NOT possible deciding which parts of data save in SteamCloud and which not.

But due to the fact that all games you named are based on Valve Source engine you can create dedicated key bindings configurations for each device you want to play on.

Create for example a file called `keybinding.cfg` and put it inside `<game_path>\cfg\`.
Launch the game with parameter `-console` and when you have loaded the game write `exec keybinding.cfg` in console.

Keybinding can be done in this way:

```
bind "key" "action"
```

a practical example:

```
bind "F1" "dota_select_courier"
```

It will take some time to configure all keybinding and find all actions but you can look to your current `cfg\config.cfg` files for reference.

disclaimer: I made this post at work and don't have the Steam folder with me, so could be that some paths or filename is incorrect. I will check them later.